# Simple Single Linked List

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I'm currently studying data structures, I have implemented simple single linked list as shown below.

I would like to know how can I improve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class List 
{
    struct node 
    {
        T value;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    };

public:
    List();

    void add(T value);

    T first() const;
    T value(std::size_t position) const;

    std::size_t length() const;
    void clear();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<node>   mFirst;
    std::size_t             mLength;
};

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
    : mFirst(nullptr)
    , mLength()
{
}

template <typename T>
std::size_t List<T>::length() const
{
    return mLength;
}

template <typename T>
T List<T>::first() const
{
    assert(mFirst != nullptr);
    return mFirst->value;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::add(T value)
{
    auto next = std::move(mFirst);
    mFirst = std::make_unique<node>();
    mFirst->value = value;
    mFirst->next = std::move(next);
    mLength++;
}

template <class T>
T List<T>::value(std::size_t position) const
{
    assert(mFirst != nullptr);

    auto current = mFirst.get();

    for (auto i = 0u; i < position; ++i)
    {
        current = current->next.get();
    }
    return current->value;
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::clear()
{
    assert(mFirst != nullptr);

    auto length = mLength;

    for (auto i = 0u; i < length; ++i)
    {
        mFirst = std::move(mFirst->next);
        mLength--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    List<int> list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        list.add(i);

    for (auto i = 0u; i < list.length(); ++i)
        std::cout << list.value(i) << ' ';

    list.clear();

    std::cout << "\n\n" << list.length() << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Small suggestion : using `class T` is not an error by itself, but what you really mean here is `typename T`. This way, you do not enforce that `T` needs to be a `class` - it just has to be a type. I haven't heard of any compilers that would give you hell if you tried to use `int` in place of a `class T`, but still. And kudos for using `size_t`!

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: `template <class T>` and `template <typename T>` mean precisely the same things to any conforming compiler. In this case, `class` does not mean that the type needs to be an actual class. Some people like to use `typename` here to indicate that any type can be passed--and that's fine, but unnecessary and irrelevant to the compiler.

Comment: @JerryCoffin : and here was I thinking that there is some kind of a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Choice of Members**

You currently keep a head pointer and a length. The result of this is that `add` is a linear operation. It would be much better to additionaly keep a tail pointer, so that `add` is constant time.

Since linked lists do not support random access, it's questionable to have a method like `T value(size_t )`. If you need to index into a container, you probably don't want to use a linked list. Better to not provide it.

Unfortunately, this is your only way to get anything other than the first value - which makes iteration take quadratic time! What you need to do is to do as the standard library do and add something like:

```
struct iterator {
    // basically a wrapper around node* that works as a ForwardIterator
};

iterator begin() { return iterator{mFirst.get()}; }
iterator end() { return iterator{mLast}; }
```

This will additionally allow everybody to use the standard library algorithms with your class. You will want a `const_iterator` as well, to allow for iteration over a `const List<T>`.

**Use References**

Right now `add()` takes a `T` and `first()` returns a `T`. For something like `int`, the former is OK, but the latter is still questionable. What if you want to modify the list elements? That seems like a useful operation. To that end, you should add:

```
void add(T const& );
void add(T&& );

T& first();
T const& first();
```

You may also want to add an `emplace`, to construct values in-place:

```
template <typename... Args>
void emplace(Args&&...);
```

You may want to rename `first` to `front` for convention. Similarly `length` to `size`.

**Clearing**

Since you are using smart pointers for your list, clearing is very simple. You don't need a loop at all:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::clear()
{
    mFirst.clear();
    mLast = nullptr;
    mLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, clearing is that simple. But doing it that way is still substandard, because there's no reason to use recursion and thus more stack-space and time.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's a good point

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's already a good review by Barry, but I'll take a different tack:

1. In general, it's a *good idea* to use existing types (like smart-pointers) as building-blocks.
   Still, you *should not* deform your code, causing loss of efficiency or clarity, just so you can use one, especially not in library-code (and such a basic container is that).

   So, no smart-pointers for you, sometimes one *really* should get down to it.
2. As an aside, your `clear` has a bug: It tries to assign the deleter after already having deleted the source. See [`std::unique_ptr::operator=(std::unique_ptr&&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D).
3. There's a reason a `node` is generally a wholly-owned passive and dumb aggregate without *any* behavior: It would just get in the way of the `List` defining it properly.
4. You should use the same names for members all the containers in the standard-library use, so you can use standard algorithms.
5. For that same reason, and so you can efficiently iterate over all elements, you should provide iterators.
6. Sacrificing some space in the class itself for a `size` can be a reaonable idea. Similar arguments can be made for including a pointer (`node**`) to the end, so you can speed up `push_back`/`emplace_back`.
7. Consider putting the next-pointer first, that *might* allow the compiler to merge code for different template-arguments more often.

---

This is how you clear a list:

```
void List::clear() {
    for(node *head = this->head, *temp; head; head = temp) {
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
    }
    this->head = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I have to disagree on the rejection of smartpointers. IMHO this is a good use of smart pointers. I do not see how their use in this example negatively impacts clarity or performance. I see no reason not to use zero-overhead stl primitives in library code. Consider that for instance std::stack also builds on other stl containers.

Comment: @Zulan: Using a smart-pointer here make `List::clear` less efficient. Especially, it means that it uses recursion, and thus O(n) space instead of O(1) space, or at least it gets more complicated and a constant factor slower.

Comment: That is plain wrong. MORTALs initial `List::clear` does not use recursion, as you correctly commented in the other answer. A well implemented clear with `unique_ptr` produces __exactly__ the same assembler code and is 
__shorter__ (see https://gist.github.com/Zulan/1d80b795afb357e94b73)

Comment: @Zulan: Yes, it's just **Undefined Behavior**, so much better: `mFirst = std::move(mFirst->next);` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D What you are also consistently ignoring is that that's basic library-code, so even a constant factor matters, if you can reasonably help it.

Comment: The constant factor is **1** [both in terms of speed and size, for my compiler with default options]. The quoted line is problematic, and should be fixed. But IMHO that doesn't warrant rejecting smart pointers. If you really wanted to, you could make a point about compilation speed and -O0 speed.